# How to make mongodb automatically use the mongod.cfg file instead of having to run it to make dbpath different?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been working with this problem for the past two days now and can't seem to figure this out or if it is possible. I am on a windows machine and using the newest version of mongodb (3.4).

I have put a mongod.cfg file in this location "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\mongod.cfg" as the mongodb docs said to do.

The file looks like this:

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: c:\Users\Amazo\mongo-data
```

I have ran the mongod.exe --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\mongod.cfg" --install , which should of installed the file from what I was getting and allow me to run mongod and start the server.

Well from what I found out it does indeed start the server with my destination path and I can open a new cmd prompt and run mongo and it is connected with my dbpath that I want. But once I close it and restart everything I run mongod and the dbpath is back to c:\data\db instead of the path I wanted.

So my question is am I going to have to run that command every time, if so I might as well pass the dbpath argument after mongod. I want to be able to just type mongod and it automatically have my dbpath that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Once your service is created using `mongod.exe --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\mongod.cfg" --install` you need to start it using `net start MongoDB`. This service will run using the configuration file specified when it was created. You shouldn't create the service again.

If it's still not working you could try with a .bat file.

Comment: This is what I get: 
`c:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>net start MongoDB`

`System error 5 has occurred.`

`Access is denied.`

Comment: Are you running CMD as administrator?

Comment: Just corrected that sorry, now I'm getting: 
`System error 2 has occurred.

The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Try to delete the service `net delete MongoDB` and create it again. Also make sure that your logs file path is correct and the file exists. If still not working, you can pass the path using parameters: `mongod.exe --logpath  "c:\data\log\mongod.log" --dbpath "c:\Users\Amazo\mongo-data" --serviceName "MongoDB" --install`

Comment: Okay I will try this tomorrow and get back with you thank you!